# Open XLSX from .bat file and dynamic name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that points to a folder with several Excel files.

This batch script needs to open an Excel file, with part of the filename always the same and part dynamic. For example:

```
Test_20170727.xlsx
AAAAA.xlsx
```

I want to open only Test_20170727.xlsx. There will be **always** only one file with Test in the name. How can I change the instruction below?

```
start EXCEL.EXE /e "C:\Folder\Test*.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

for Excel 2016, try this in your batchfile:

```
for %%i in (c:\temp\test*.xlsx) do ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%%i")
```

or directly from the commandline:

```
for %i in (c:\temp\test*.xlsx) do ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%i")
```

this will open every xlsx file in `C:\temp` starting with the string `test`.

Comment: Your `*test*.xlsx` matching method will also match files like `atesta.xlsx`. But the OP only wanted to match `test*.xlsx`, please change your answer